# Cannot use RedisIndexedSessionRepository in service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

For my spring-boot application (2.3.3.RELEASE, Java 11) I uses spring session, here is a standard dependencies for this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

*The application works as expected, sessions stores in redis and managed by spring as well.*

***But*** I want to delete sessions by id from Redis manually. For this I noticed that spring has a bean for session repository in RedisHttpSessionConfiguration (line 119):

```
@Bean
public RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
```

And I decided to reuse it. Unfortunately, when I try that in my service like:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SessionService {
    private final RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository;
```

****the following error appears while application starts*:***

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
```

UPD. I found that if I add RedisIndexedSessionRepository  to my service Spring somehow doesn't execute the code responsible for setting redisConnectionFactory in RedisHttpSessionConfiguration (autowired method setRedisConnectionFactory, line 204). But if I remove RedisIndexedSessionRepository from my service the above method are triggered. I also tried to create my own bean RedisConnectionFactory but it doesn't fix this.

Ahh, I found this comment in RedisHttpSessionConfiguration on top:

```
 * Exposes the {@link SessionRepositoryFilter} as a bean named
 * {@code springSessionRepositoryFilter}. In order to use this a single
 * {@link RedisConnectionFactory} must be exposed as a Bean.
```

but still don't understand ***how to use RedisIndexedSessionRepository in service***.

Could someone advice how to handle that and how to use this repository in application?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that RedisIndexedSessionRepository cannot be simply autowired and we have do that manually like:

```
private final RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository;

public SessionService(RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate) {
    this.sessionRepository = new RedisIndexedSessionRepository(redisTemplate);
}
```